# Is socket descriptor basically a synonym of a file descriptor?

Tags: file, sockets, unix, networking

From: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

> So when you want to communicate with another program over the Internet
> you're gonna do it through a file descriptor, you'd better believe it.
>
> “Where do I get this file descriptor for network communication, Mr.
> Smarty-Pants?” is probably the last question on your mind right now,
> but I'm going to answer it anyway: You make a call to the socket()
> system routine. It returns the socket descriptor, and you communicate
> through it using the specialized send() and recv() (man send, man
> recv) socket calls.
>
> “But, hey!” you might be exclaiming right about
> now. “If it's a file descriptor, why in the name of Neptune can't I
> just use the normal read() and write() calls to communicate through
> the socket?” The short answer is, “You can!” The longer answer is,
> “You can, but send() and recv() offer much greater control over your
> data transmission.”

Since, socket is a way of communication between different processes in UNIX,
and
all communication between different processes in UNIX is done by reading and writing to a file,
and
a file descriptor is an integer that uniquely represents an open file in an operating system.

**So, is socket descriptor basically a file descriptor?

OR is socket descriptor basically a unique identification to the established link between two programs?**

What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several questions here, but the answer to all of them is the same. On Unix, Linux, etc., a socket descriptor *is* a file descriptor. That's *why* you can use read() and write() and close().

On Windows, it isn't, and you can't.

Comment: thankful. please explain what is it on windows then.

Comment: It is a socket descriptor only, allocated by WINSOCK, and that has no other use outside the WINSOCK API.